# Rails 3.2 Routing: multiple defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, defaults

I am using two default parameters within my routes:

```
scope '(/:locale)(/:currency)', currency: /eur|usd/, locale: /de|en/, defaults: { currency: 'eur' } do ...
```

Because the currency should be used for the whole visit, I added locale and currency to the default_url_options in the ApplicationController:

```
def default_url_options options = {}
 { locale: I18n.locale, currency: params['currency'] }
end
```

When I generate URLs, i.e. with url_for(), Rails forgets about the currency by default. It only works, when I add it manually. For example:

```
root_path(currency: params['currency'])
```

I would like this to be added by default (of course). There is no problem with *locale*. Rails handles that correctly. (Perhaps because of the globalize3 gem?)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: what version of rails?

Comment: I just tested it and it worked for me. Could you put the route helper call and context, the resulting URL, and the desired URI in your question, please?

Comment: I take that back, I hadn't replicated it exactly; it seems to be the `defaults` part of the routing scope that's messing it up, I'll have a play.

Comment: Thanks! Rails sometimes adds currency as a query string to URLs, i.e. `http://domain.com/de?currency=eur`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your routes are mapped, the defaults from the route declarations are stored in a hash. When you call your route helper `foo_path`, these defaults are passed as a hash of options to [`ActionDispatch::Routing.url_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L150):

```
def url_for(options = nil)
  case options
  when nil
    _routes.url_for(url_options.symbolize_keys)
  when Hash
    _routes.url_for(options.symbolize_keys.reverse_merge!(url_options))
  when String
    options
  else
    polymorphic_url(options)
  end
end
```

Now, as we're receiving a hash, it `reverse_merge!`s with `url_options` (where your default from overriding the `default_url_options` is declared!). As it's a `reverse_merge!` it means that the values in `options` take precedence over that in `url_options`, so the default value for `currency` will always be what it is set to in the routes file, regardless of what you put in your `default_url_options` in your `ApplicationController`. These defaults then get passed onto a chain of `url_for` methods and the like, and your path is returned.

What's more, the currency parameter gets removed from your returned path completetely, with [these lines of code](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/master/lib/journey/route.rb#L71):

```
def format path_options
  path_options.delete_if do |key, value|
    value.to_s == defaults[key].to_s && !required_parts.include?(key)
  end

  Visitors::Formatter.new(path_options).accept(path.spec)
end
```

It determines that the default value in your `path_options` (`'eur'`) is equivalent to the `defaults` from where it was selected (duhhh?), so it removes it for some reason.

So what we've learnt is that the defaults in your routes file will always take precedence over `url_options`.

My advice therefore, would be to remove the `defaults:` key from your routing scope, and then you will always have a `:currency` parameter in your URL, and you can specify the default in the controller.

Comment: Thank you alot! I really misinterpreted the `defaults` option. Now I set the default value with the default_url_options (if params[:currency] is my default, don't include it in links).